# Can't make OpenCV scr parameter to take string input

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV function on last line doesn't take my `img` argument. If I do
`imglink = r 'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\asdf.png'`
everything works.

`Print(imglink)` outputs `r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\asdf.png'`.

Code:

```py
import pytesseract

name_of_file = "asdf"

imglink = "r" "\'" + "C:\\Users\\1\\Desktop\\ImagetoText\\" + name_of_file + ".png\'"


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Users\\1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img = cv.imread(imglink)
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

The error I get is:
`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugging variant 2 (that worked) of `imglink` outputted C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\asdf.png instead of r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\asdf.png' so I modified `imglink` to make just that, now it works perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunetely the code only runs well in PyCharm, gives similar error in VS Code. I have now posted separate question about this.